# Is perl's file check IO intensive?

Tags: linux, perl, scripting

I've come up with a way to turn on debugging without having to edit any scripts.  Simply touching the filename with .debug turns on my debugging.

```
$ touch fancy.pl.debug
```

My fear is that the filecheck (Being at the very start of EVERY script) might be IO intensive in some way

```
$opts{d}++ if (-e "$0.debug");
```

Could this be true?  Is there a better way to do this check or turn on/off debugging in many scripts?

Comment: An alternative would be to set an environment variable... just a thought

Comment: Measure it! A call to stat() isn't _that_ expensive. But really: break out your watch (or Time::HiRes) and measure it.

Comment: What is "intensive" by your standards? A single file check should be no more intensive than the real world equivalence of a butterfly taking off rather angrily. I.e. hardly noticeable to any human senses.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a directory read. It should be light.

Comment: And if the files are in the same directory, it will probably be cached, so even lighter.